# Determinate progress indicator with AppleScript-Objc

Tags: applescript-objc

I would like to know how I can create a due hereunder progress indicator that shows me real information of the file that I am downloading or is download speed and how much time is remaining to complete, I tried an example that I saw here and it works but Does not seem to provide me with actual data. I wanted something like the one in the picture attached, could you help me?
Thanks in advance!!

```
set c to 0
            repeat 100 times
                set c to c + 1
                delay 0.04
                tell ProgressIndicator to setDoubleValue_(c) 
                if c > 99 then
                    exit repeat
                end if
                end repeat
```

[image: Example of what I want to do]

Comment: Can you please share your relevant code pertaining to the data you are downloading so we can see what methods you are using?  Essentially, if you are using `NSURLSession` and related class methods, your delegate will receive notifications during a download that contains information about how much data has been received and how much is expected in total.

Comment: @CJK I'm using a shell command: "do shell script curl -L ......" I do not know if this is the best way, I believe it is not, if you have any better suggestions please tell me.

Comment: The file information is created with the [Progress](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/progress) class. You need a network API which provides dynamically data about the amount of downloaded bytes.

Comment: @vadian Any API or at least something that gives me the correct download time even without any info?

Comment: Any API which indicates and updates the current number of downloaded bytes. `curl` does not work.